# Reference Request: Diophantine Equations

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations

I'm a third-year undergraduate looking to tackle some math I wanted to learn a while ago: Diophantine Equations. I spent some time researching how to solve ceiling and floor type of problems, and know about Hilbert's tenth problem states that not all diophantine equations can be solved generally.

In my effort to learn more about these types of useful equations, can someone recommend me a book or two on solving Diophantine Equations? Books on this subject or ones that are very closely related are all acceptable.

Comment: You should be able to read Mordell. https://books.google.com/books/about/Diophantine_equations.html?id=QugvF7xfE-oC

Comment: Intended to allow self-study  https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Comment: Try Silverman's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*; lots of fun material in there relevant to solving Diophantine equations like the Mordell equations $y^2 = x^3 + n$: https://www.amazon.com/Rational-Points-Elliptic-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387978259

Comment: I found [this reader](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf) to be a great introduction to algebraic number theory.